# there are a lot of people from them on the committee

Tags: sentence-structure

> Local businesses are well represented on the committee (= there **are a lot of people from them on the committee**).

Source: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/represent?q=Represent+

---

It seems to me that "**from them**" modifies "**a lot of people**" and that "**on the committee**" modifies "**are**". I'm not sure.
What do "**from them**" and "**on the committee**" modify respectively?
I don't know if I'm expressing my thoughts well.

Comment: There are a lot of people **from local businesses** on the committee.

Comment: Better to my ear: *A lot of people from local businesses **are** on the committee.* Much better: ***Many** people from local businesses...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd like to ask some questions. Is the "**a lot of people from them on the committee**" in "there are **a lot of people from them on the committee**" a noun phrase?

Comment: Yes, it's a noun phrase. For which the "head noun" is ***lot***, modified by preposition-based adjectival phrase ***of people***, giving an internal component which is itself a noun phrase. Then *that* noun phrase is modified by another preposition-based adjectival phrase ***on the committee***. English is very much a "recursive" language, so you can have *noun phrases within noun phrases within... ([turtles all the way down!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "There **is** *a cat* on the table" is the same as "*A cat* **is** on the table". Therefore, it seems to me that the "*a cat* on the table" in "There **is** *a cat* on the table" is not a noun phrase because "on the table" modifies "**is**". I wonder where I am wrong.

Comment: I can't really help you with that. I learned English the same way as every other native Anglophone, by hearing, speaking, listening, and reading. And even though I got my *degree* in English half a century ago, I've never needed to know exactly how to define "a noun" in contexts like your examples. Bear in mind any given string of words isn't "a noun" in and of itself - you can only assign such a "part of speech" label to the word *when they're used in a valid utterance*...

Comment: I think it's axiomatic that the construction *There **is** a/an XXXX* implies XXXX is being used as a noun. And *A/An YYYY **is** [prepositional phrase]* implies / entails that YYYY is a noun usage. The fact that you can find examples where XXXX is equal to YYYY ***plus*** [prepositional phrase] doesn't make any difference, just as it makes no difference that you can ***table*** a motion (a verb usage), but ***table*** in these examples is always a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In "How many **days** are there **in February**?, does "**days**" form a noun phrase with "**in February**"? It seems not because "How many days are there in February" are more natural than "How many days in February are there". What do you say?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. Obviously ***days*** is a plural noun in *How many days are there in February?* My first reaction to *How many days in February are there* is to say that I don't think the construction *How many X's in Y are there?* is ever valid except in contrived contexts where "X's in Y" is an established noun phrase that can't be broken up, such as *How many ladies in waiting are there on the royal payroll?* Honestly, I can't teach you what a noun phrase is in comments here. Ask the community, or do some more research.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the "in February" in "There are 28 days in February" is a preposition-based adjectival phrase. I wonder if the "in February" in "How many days are there in February?" is also a preposition-based adjectival phrase. This is the last question. Thank you.

Comment: English syntax is "recursive", meaning that in a noun phrase like *7 days in a week*, the "head noun" is ***days***, but there's another noun ***week*** in the ***preposition-based*** adjectival/adverbial phrase ***in a week***, which is itself *part* of the complete noun phrase *7 days in a week* (where ***7*** is another component adjectival phrase usage that *doesn't* involve a preposition). But *please* don't ask me to explain the difference between an adjective and an adverb! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Them' is the only pronoun here and refers, as you correctly guessed, to the local businesses mentioned in the sentence being explained.

You also asked what 'the committee' referred to. It refers to the same committee mentioned in the previous sentence being explained. Who is this mystery committee? We don't know; it's an example from a dictionary so there is no context.